# How to include cell value in a function

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to reference a cell in this JSON import script.

I need to reference the cell B5 after where it says /people/

The value of B5 is 8471695

```
=VALUE(ImportJSON("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/"=b5"", "/people/currentAge", "noHeaders"))
```

I am getting an error when doing this.

The spreadsheet can be viewed here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NJhDWOGWlleK88hDaVstdTnUOpd78j2gDHQogDSqt6w/edit#gid=206010836

Hopefully, if this gets working, I can drag it down the other columns below, so it starts referencing B6, B7, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=VALUE(ImportJSON("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/"&B5, "/people/currentAge", "noHeaders"))
```

and see if that works?